# Discounted Costs

Tags: discounting

Suppose we were given a discounted cost of £12,956.

This was generated using a discount factor of 3.5% and a time-horizon of 45 years.

Is it possible to obtain what the non-discounted cost is today? That is to say, if £12.956 was the outcome of a discounting process, is it possible to attain the cost at time period 1, undiscounted (given this is a once off cost, and nothing to do with revenue and NPV).

For clarity, this is not as part of a test. Instead, it is an intellectual curiosity, where I simplified the figures taken from Page 4, Paragraph 4 of this paper:

https://www.england.nhs.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/patent-foramen-ovale-closure-evaluation-report.pdf

All feedback would be appreciated,

Best,

Andrew